# Windows 8 and Salesforce

Tags: force.com, windows8

Has anyone run into any issues on Salesforce on windows 8 touch screen laptops? I'm asked to look into potential issues that we might face

off the top of my head- visualforce pages might be an issue ( maybe some input methods don't play nicely with win 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not typically OS related, but instead Browser related.  Here are the [browsers supported by Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getstart_browser_overview.htm).

You can specifically [detect touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761078/detect-touch-events-in-chrome-on-windows-8-with-touchscreen) in VF pages, but since they can translate to clicks, right clicks, etc., you should be set without it.